# Hellinger Integral properties

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu , \nu$ be two probability measures on $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}).$  Suppose we have a probability measure $\lambda$ such that both $\mu , \nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.  Define $H(\mu,\nu)=\int_\Omega \sqrt{\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}}d\lambda$.  My book lists several properties of this value.  I was able to prove most of these; however, I was unable to show

$H(\mu,\nu)=1 \implies \mu=\nu$.

Also, it stated that $H(\mu,\nu)>0$ does not imply that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are equivalent.  There was no counterexample provided nor I could think of one.  Could someone please provide this counterexample and the proof of the above property.  Thanks!